# Procurar uma sub-string na primeira coluna de um arquivo csv

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, csv

Estou iniciando o aprendizado em python e não sei como dar prosseguimento a esse código.

Preciso verificar a primeira coluna de um arquivo csv, e caso NÃO tenha uma data em uma célula dessa coluna, inserir a que foi passada como parâmetro.

```
import csv
import sys

lendo_arquivo = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'))
escrevendo_arquivo = csv.writer(open(sys.argv[2], 'wb'))

    for linhas in lendo_arquivo:

    if linhas[0] == "201":
        pass
    else:
        escrevendo_arquivo.writerow([sys.argv[3] + ";"] + linhas)
```

Cheguei nesse ponto, onde ele adiciona o 3° parâmetro mesmo que a célula tenha  "201" e ainda acrescenta uma "," (vírgula) no final da célula.

> 201 é a substring de uma data, ex: 2018

O que posso fazer para ignorar a célula que tenha "201" e remover essa vírgula do final???

Comment: Poste algumas linhas do arquivo. Algumas que tenham o 201 e outras que não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que seu arquivo `.CSV` de entrada seja algo como (`entrada.csv`):

```
2018;ALPHA;3.1415
2018;BETA;1.4142
2007;GAMMA;1.7320
2018;DELTA;2.7182
2007;EPSILON;2.2543
```

Segue o programa em `Python` capaz de realizar a filtragem do arquivo (`filtro.py`):

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as csv_saida:
    saida = csv.writer( csv_saida, delimiter=';' )
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as csv_entrada:
        entrada = csv.reader( csv_entrada, delimiter=';' )
        for linha in entrada:
            if not linha[0].startswith("201"):
                saida.writerow( [ sys.argv[3] ] + linha[1:] )
```

Linha de comando:

```
python3 filtro.py entrada.csv saida.csv 1970
```

Saída (`saida.csv`):

```
1970;GAMMA;1.7320
1970;EPSILON;2.2543
```